# Easiest way to forward mail to a third-party email address

Tags: email

I have some home system monitoring scripts run via cron that will create output, and hence mail to the user that runs the script. I want to redirect this mail to my Gmail (or insert any other third-party mail) account.

The method should

1. be able to authenticate with and use another SMTP server (e.g. Gmail's SMTP itself) rather than sending directly via sendmail etc, as services like Gmail are likely to mark my mail as spam if I don't use a legit service.
2. retry sending if failed as it will be run via a home Internet connection.

Comment: is your machine running a mail server locally you can send mail to for forwarding to the outside? I think this is pretty standard for Linux. Often mail servers on desktop machines without static IPs (eg on cable internet) set up their local mail servers to send their mails to a smarthost, and have everything send their mail to the local mail server. Retry is usually automatically done by the smarthost for a period of time, I believe 4 days or so. Of course, you could bypass the local mail server entirely. In any case, `mail` is commonly used for scripts.

Answer (score 2):

One very simple way to do this (and it may not meet all your requirments, it's so simple) is to use a `.forward` file in the $HOME directory of the user ID that runs the cron job.

You just put a 3rd party email address in .forward, and it appears that [sendmail does the rest](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.files/doc/aixfiles/forward.htm).

You can use .forward to run the email through a program.  My .forward file says this: "|exec /usr/bin/procmail"

procmail is a fairly primitive mail filtering program that works well enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Install a local MTA, such as `exim`, and configure it to use a `smarthost`, in this case either your ISP's mail server or google's (the latter possibly better if you are concerned about the SMTP reputation of your home IP).

Then, set up forwarding for your user.  There are many ways to do this. With `exim` on Debian, you can edit `/etc/aliases` and set `foo: foo@gmail.com`.  Another approach would be to create `~/.forward` containing `foo@gmail.com`, but that means your `$HOME` needs to be available at the time mail is sent (not always the case for me, my `$HOME` is only mounted on log in).

A good MTA (such as `exim`) will support smarthosts and also do retries.

Comment: He already has sendmail which also supports smart hosts, aliases and authentication.

Comment: It's not clear that he does have sendmail; merely that he's familiar with it and doesn't think it can solve his problem.